# Implement edit and review modes in html/webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, resize

I want to implement edit and review modes in my webpage. 
In edit mode the user can drag and drop divs to other some location or resize the divs.

Now suppose after making changes the user wants to review his/her work done so far. For this I put a link there that will allow the user to go to review mode. 
In  this review mode the user should not be able to make changes(disabling the drag and drop facilities).

Any Idea how to do this???

Answer (score 1):

Your post is very vague. Please post some code.

To disable dragging use this code:

```
$(".selector").draggable("option", "disabled", false);
```

To enable it use:

```
$(".selector")draggable("option", "disabled", true);
```

see: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/